# Is it possible to review on the mobile site?

Tags: support

I have free time while I am about. I could review questions with my phone. Is it possible on the mobile site? I can't find a link to the review part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no mobile review.

You can try accessing the full site review though.  Not especially easy to do, but it works.  There isn't that much to review at any one time anyway.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks. Works well enough on the full site.