# Mobile-friendly version of review page?

Tags: feature-request

The main Ask Ubuntu page works great with my brand-name-smartphone and I'd love to see the functionality of the site extended by making the review page (askubuntu.com/review) also mobile-friendly.

Will this be implemented? If so, is there a timeframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6041/is-it-possible-to-review-on-the-mobile-site

Comment: Mod screens would be nice too. There aren't even links to some mod functions from the mobile site which is really annoying when you need to destroy a spam user.